# What is the solution for 'getter for buildDir: File!' is deprecated

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to upgrade gradle version and getting the following error

```
'getter for buildDir: File!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
```

But not able to find an alternate solution to this anywhere.

My code that is using buildDir is like this

```
"${this@allprojects.buildDir/path}"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You now need to use:

```
project.layout.buildDirectory
```

See the [version 8 upgrade instructions](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_8.html#project_builddir).

This will give you a [`DirectoryProperty`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/DirectoryProperty.html) rather than a Java `File` (using Gradle's [lazy configuration API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html)).

You will then have to use further methods to use it. Calling `get().getAsFile()` will immediately access the `File` object, but you should use the it lazily wherever possible (so Gradle can complete the project configuration smoothly).